# React | Charset remove numeric' on keydown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Remove numeric'**

So my problem is that I have written a little charset function, that takes all numbers from  0-9, and atm I have just console.log'ged them, but when I have tried to remove the numeric' keys from 0-9 when typed into my input, it won't work. This code will show it as a return false.

```
    function reg(e) {
    const char = e.which;
    if (char >= 48 && char <= 57) { return false }
}

return (
    <> 
        <form onSubmit={validate}>

            <input type="text"
                onKeyDown={reg}
                value={usernameValue} 
                placeholder="name" 
                onChange={setUsernameValue} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `false`, you should prevent the default event behaviour. This is a very common trick in JS event handlers.

It looks like this:

```
function reg(e) {
    const char = e.which;
    if (char >= 48 && char <= 57) { e.preventDefault() }
}
```